# How can we show that the time shift $t\mapsto x(s+\;\cdot\;)$ is measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

This is a question of great importance and hence there should be an answer in any textbook on stochastic processes. However, I neither found it nor I know how to approach this:

Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space and $s\ge0$. Moreover, let $$\tau_s:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)\;\;\;t\mapsto s+t$$ and $$\theta_s:E^{[0,\:\infty)}\to E^{[0,\:\infty)}\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto x\circ\tau_s.$$

> How do we show that $\theta_s$ is $\left(\mathcal E^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)},\mathcal E^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)}\right)$-measurable?

Moreover, what does happen if $E$ is a metric space and we restrict $\theta_s$ to

1. the Skorohod space $D([0,\infty),E)$ of càdlàg functions from $[0,\infty)\to E$ equipped with the Skorohod metric?
2. the space of continuous functions equipped with the supremum norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A map $(F, \mathcal{F}) \to (E^{[0, \infty)}, \mathcal{E}^{\otimes [0, \infty)})$ *into* $E^{[0, \infty)}$ is $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{E}^{\otimes[0, \infty)}$-measurable if and only if all of its (all $t \geq 0$) compositions with the canonical projections
$$
\pi_t \colon E^{[0, \infty)} \to E,
\pi_t(x) = x(t),
$$ are $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{E}$ measurable.
That's more or less the definition of the product sigma algebra.

With your map $\theta_s$ it is
$$
(\pi_t \circ \theta_s)(x) = \pi_t(x(\cdot + s)) = x(t+s) = \pi_{t+s}(x),
$$
i.e.
$$
\pi_t \circ \theta_s = \pi_{t+s}
$$ a canonical projection again.
Therefore $\pi_t \circ \theta_s$ is measurable for all $t, s \geq 0$.
This shows the measurability of $\theta_s$ as map  $(E^{[0, \infty)}, \mathcal{E}^{\otimes [0, \infty)}) \to  (E^{[0, \infty)}, \mathcal{E}^{\otimes [0, \infty)})$.

For the Skorokhod space and the space of continuous functions the same proof works because the corresponding Borel sigma algebras are generated by the canonical projections too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we weven show that $$E^{[0,\:\infty)}\times[0,\infty)\to E^{[0,\:\infty)}\;,\;\;\;(x,s)\mapsto\theta_s(x)$$ is $\left(\mathcal E^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)}\otimes\mathcal B([0,\infty)),\mathcal E^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)}\right)$-measurable?

Comment: I dont think that is true in general. 
Denote your map by $\psi$.
Fix a non-measurable $x_0 \in E^{[0, \infty)}$.
Consider the measurable map $i \colon [0, \infty) \to  E^{[0, \infty)} \times [0, \infty), s \mapsto (x_0, s)$.
Then we have
$(\pi_0 \circ \psi \circ i)(s) = \pi_0(x_0(\cdot + s)) = x_0(s)$.
This map is not measurable, but it had to be if $\psi$ were measurable.

Comment: Hm, first of all: Is $x_0\in\mathcal E^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)}$ if and only if $x_0:[0,\infty)\to E$ is $(\mathcal B([0,\infty)),\mathcal E)$-measurable?

Comment: No, $E^{[0, \infty)}$ consists of *all* functions $[0, \infty) \to E$.